# html css hierarchical table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to generate a HTML page that shows a tree structure of parent and child objects, This is the excel version.

http://screencast.com/t/xZtkgSUsO (screen shot of current system)

I can make the chart show from top to bottom, but it becomes messy once there is too much text.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvw7yv05/   (example)

```
<table border CELLSPACING=5 cellpadding="10" width="700px">
   <tr>
      <td colspan=18>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan = 6>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td colspan = 4>a load of text here, more more more more more more</td>
      <td colspan = 3>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td colspan = 4>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td><a href="addnew">Add New</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td><a href="addnew">Add New</a></td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td><a href="addnew">Add New</a></td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td><a href="addnew">Add New</a></td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td>hello dfgdfg dfgdfgdfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgfd dfgdfgdf</td>
      <td><a href="addnew">Add New</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure Tables are the best way to complete this, if so.
So I have two problems,

1) Is there a nice way I can hide the text as I don't want the width to go over around 700px? show hide functionality

2) The 4th row will have set of child elements, if I start putting text in each cell it will look really nasty. Any ideas on how to make this look presentable.

I can't be the first person to try this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This is a very broad question with quite a lot of potential solutions.  Perhaps you start trying to solve this and then ask a question if you get stuck?

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for the response, I've been working on this for along time - Can you give me a pointer ? best method, my html tables aren't doing the job!

Comment: What you probaply need is rowspans and colspans which you find here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xcregz9d/

To hide overflowing text you can create div inside each cell and add following properties

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

It's going to pull all text in one line, hide overflowing content and add `...` at the end.